# Problem with predicte pushing in a Max and Min statistic about each user in a group

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, group-by

I have two tables in an ORACLE 10g DB:

The table USERS with columns:
UserId | GroupId | Other details
where there's 1 record for each User, total 400, and there c.a. 1-10 users in each Group.

and the table USAGE with columns:
UserId | Date | Amount
where there's 10000 rows for each user. (so 400*10000 rows)

I have the Users table indexed on UserId, GroupId and (UserId,GroupId) and the table Usage  is indexed on (UserId,Date)

I want to see the  Max and Total amount of usage for each user in a given group. 
Something like this:

```
select User.UserId, maxAmount, Total from 
Users
JOIN
( select UserId,max(Amount) as maxAmount from USAGE group by UserId ) A
ON User.UserId = A.UserId
JOIN 
(  select UserId,min(Amount) as minAmount from USAGE group by UserId ) B
ON User.UserId = B.UserId
WHERE User.GroupId = 'some_group_id'
```

But it is very slow (approx 20 sec), but when I do them separately (just Max and just Min, but not both at once), like this:

```
select User.UserId, maxAmount, minAmount from 
Users
JOIN
( select UserId,max(Amount) as maxAmount from USAGE group by UserId ) A
ON User.UserId = A.UserId
WHERE User.GroupId = 'some_group_id'
```

it runs in a flash!

It just makes no sense that I can join them separately very fast, but when I join them all three it's very slow.

Here are the plans, where I created the inline views in the preceeding statements as actual views:

```
create view usage_min as select user_id, min(amount) from usage group by user_id;
create view usage_max as select user_id, max(amount) from usage group by user_id;




 explain plan for select * from usage_min join users using(user_id) where group_id='1212882339';
 select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
Plan hash value: 3874246446

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                 |     1 |   139 |  1162   (1)| 00:00:14 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                    |                 |     1 |   139 |  1162   (1)| 00:00:14 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | USAGE           |  7977 |   116K|  1157   (1)| 00:00:14 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                   |                 | 11085 |  1504K|  1160   (1)| 00:00:14 |
|   4 |     MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| USERS           |     1 |   124 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN             | USERS_KT        |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN              | SYS_C0099818    |  7977 |       |    79   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - access("USERS"."group_id"='1212882339')
   6 - access("user_id"="USERS"."user_id")


  explain plan for select * from users join  usage_max   using(user_id) where group_id='1212882339';
 select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 2384977958

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                 |     1 |   145 |   519   (2)| 00:00:07 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                    |                 |     1 |   145 |   519   (2)| 00:00:07 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | USAGE2          | 18251 |   374K|   512   (1)| 00:00:07 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                   |                 | 25362 |  3591K|   515   (1)| 00:00:07 |
|   4 |     MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| USERS           |     1 |   124 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN             | USERS_KT        |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN              | T2_user_id        | 18251 |       |    25   (4)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   5 - access("USERS"."group_id"='1212882339')
   6 - access("USERS"."user_id"="user_id")

 explain plan for select * from  users  join usage_max using(user_id) join  usage_min using(user_id)  where group_id='1212882339';
 select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);

Plan hash value: 3190011991

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                         | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                  |                 |   100 | 16600 |  6782  (19)| 00:01:22 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN                        |                 |   100 | 16600 |  6782  (19)| 00:01:22 |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN                      |                 |   100 | 14500 |  3176  (19)| 00:00:39 |
|   3 |    SORT JOIN                      |                 |  2920K|    58M|  3172  (19)| 00:00:39 |
|   4 |     VIEW                          | USAGE_MAX       |  2920K|    58M|  3172  (19)| 00:00:39 |
|   5 |      HASH GROUP BY                |                 |  2920K|    58M|  3172  (19)| 00:00:39 |
|   6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL           | USAGE2          |  2920K|    58M|  2686   (5)| 00:00:33 |
|*  7 |    SORT JOIN                      |                 |     1 |   124 |     4  (25)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |     MAT_VIEW ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| USERS           |     1 |   124 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN             | USERS_KT        |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |   VIEW                            | USAGE_MIN       |   398 |  8358 |  3605  (19)| 00:00:44 |
|  11 |    HASH GROUP BY                  |                 |   398 |  5970 |  3605  (19)| 00:00:44 |
|  12 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL             | USAGE           |  3174K|    45M|  3073   (4)| 00:00:37 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("USAGE_MAX"."user_id"="USAGE_MIN"."user_id")
   7 - access("USERS"."user_id"="USAGE_MAX"."user_id")
       filter("USERS"."user_id"="USAGE_MAX"."user_id")
   9 - access("USERS"."group_id"='1212882339')
```

Answer (score 1):

- What are the query plans?
- Are you measuring the time to fetch the first row?  Or are you measuring the time to fetch the last row?

At a minimum, I'd want to hit the `USAGE` table just once using something like

```
select User.UserId, maxAmount, Total from 
Users
JOIN
( select UserId,
         max(Amount) as maxAmount,
         sum(Amount) as Total
    from USAGE group by UserId ) A
ON User.UserId = A.UserId
WHERE User.GroupId = 'some_group_id'
```

or even more simply

```
SELECT user.userId,
       max(usage.Amount) maxAmount,
       sum(usage.Amount) total
  FROM user
       join usage on (user.userId = usage.userId)
 WHERE user.GroupId = 'some_group_id'
 GROUP BY user.userId
```

Comment: Sorry, my problem is simplified version of another setup where the aggregate operator is not working on the same subset of rows. (So I need to do it in two seperate hits). The problem is that when I do both in the same query It does not push the predicate into the aggregate inline views.

Comment: @Eirikur - Can you post an example that shows the problem you're trying to solve?  Can you post the plans that demonstrate that the predicate is not being pushed?  Could you use analytic functions to hit the table once rather than scanning it twice to get the two aggregates?

Comment: Regarding demonstration, see edited question. I substituted the inline views with actual views but it should not matter.